# error in flask hello world program cannot import flask

Tags: python, flask

```
$ python app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import FLASK
ImportError: cannot import name 'FLASK' from 'flask' (/Users/kiran/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/__init__.py)
```

Comment: should be `Flask` not `FLASK`. Python is case sensitive.

Comment: `from flask import Flask`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mistakenly capitalized `flask`. It should be:

```
from flask import Flask
```

Answer (score 0):

Here **FLASK* Representation is wrong,instead of FLASK write Flask

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
  return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run()
```